# Using too many Open calls. How do I close all files?

Tags: python, io

I'm trying to change a lot of pdf-files. Because of this I must open a lot of files. I use the method open to many times. So python gives the error ***too many open files***.

I hope my code is grace.writer many too similar

```
readerbanner = PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader(open('transafe.pdf', 'rb'))
readertestpages = PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(Cache_path, cache_file_name), 'rb'))
writeroutput.write(open(os.path.join(Output_path,cache_file_name), 'wb'))

or

writer_output.write(open(os.path.join(Cache_path, str(NumPage) + "_" + pdf_file_name), 'wb'))
reader_page_x = PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(PDF_path, pdf_file_name), 'rb'))
```

All the open methods do not use ***f_name = open("path","r")***.

because all open file have period. I know the position but not know how close all open files.

Comment: need class or method in  open calls and push list..At the end of the period use ***for i in files_list:i.close()***..but can't find a good way

Answer (score 3):

To close a file just call `close()` on it.

You can also use a context manager which handles file closing for you:

```
with open('file.txt') as myfile:
    # do something with myfile here

# here myfile is automatically closed
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, this code should not open too many files. Unless it is run a lot of times.

Regardless, the problem consists of you calling:

```
PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader(open('transafe.pdf', 'rb'))
```

and similar. This creates a file object, but saves no reference to it.
What you need to do for all open calls is:

```
file = open('transafe.pdf', 'rb')
PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader(file)
```

And then:

```
file.close()
```

when you do not use the file anymore.
If you want to close many files at the same time, put them in a list.

Comment: With the PdfFileReader object in particular, I am finding that if I try to save the file pointer and then close it later, or if I encase it within a with statement, that causes the pdf to become corrupted.  It would be good just to be able to tell Python to close all open files after everything with pdfs is done.

Answer (score 1):

#### with statement

```py
with open("abc.txt", "r") as file1, open("123.txt", "r") as file2:
    # use files
    foo = file1.readlines()

# they are closed automatically
print(file1.closed)
# -> True
print(file2.closed)
# -> True
```

#### wrapper function

```py
files = []
def my_open(*args):
    f = open(*args)
    files.append(f)
    return f

# use my_open
foo = my_open("text.txt", "r")

# close all files
list(map(lambda f: f.close(), files))
```

#### wrapper class

```py
class OpenFiles():
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = []

    def open(self, *args):
        f = open(*args)
        self.files.append(f)
        return f

    def close(self):
        list(map(lambda f: f.close(), self.files))


files = OpenFiles()

# use open method
foo = files.open("text.txt", "r")

# close all files
files.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExitStack` can be useful:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in filenames]
    # All opened files will automatically be closed at the end of
    # the with statement, even if attempts to open files later
    # in the list raise an exception
```